# Custom notification in react-admin dashboard [react-admin version: "^3.2.3"]

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, custom-notification

onSuccess property does not work in the Edit and Create component
I am using react-admin dashboard panel and I WANT TO DISPLAY CUSTOM NOTIFICATION

MY CODE

[image]

ERROR

[image]

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `onSuccess` prop was added in react-admin 3.6.0 (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/releases/tag/v3.6.0). If you're using a version lower than that, this prop isn't handled.

Remember to always look at the documentation for your release number in the react-admin doc (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Readme.html).